# WPF How to point to a file path for a resource, so it can be used by the program on any machine?

Tags: wpf, uri, filepath

Hello I am making a WPF application with a song playing in the background. However the song won't play on a machine that isn't mine. Does anyone here know how to set a default path for the program to search? Here is my code right now...

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer();

    private MediaPlayer m_mediaPlayer;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        m_mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        m_mediaPlayer.Open(new Uri(@"\\Music\Song.wav"));

        m_mediaPlayer.Volume = 1 / 100.0f;
        m_mediaPlayer.Play();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put it in the same directory as the exe? Or if its not to big, you can embed it as a resource.